# MyProperty not updated in PropertyChangedCallBack

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, propertychanged

Is there a CallBack After `PropertyChangedCallBack` ? because in the `PropertyChangedCallBack` the change hasn't been made yet.
In the example below after I set `MyProperty` and when `Foo()` is being called, `MyProperty` still got the old value in `Foo()`. 
I want to be able to call `Foo()` just after I change `MyProperty` with the new value

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0, MyProperty_PropertyChanged));

private static void MyProperty_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var self = (ownerclass)d;
    d.Foo();
}

void Foo()
{
    //-->old value of MyProperty
}
```

Comment: You can get the new value from the [event args](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertychangedeventargs.newvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).